# Manga with a girl having demons in her hands and hunts vampires

Tags: crimezone

There’s this manga where, in the beginning, a boy is in school and sees a hot girl. She lures him to some isolated garden outside or something and tries to eat him (take his blood and stuff). A girl in his class, who is always seen sleeping, comes and rescues him by blowing up the vampire girl’s brains and stabbing its heart. The girl has two seals in her hands, and she usually uses only her right hand that has this monster/demon that can kill vampires. The monster-arm girl has a mission to kill all of the pure blood vampires (7 powerful women). She has a little girl sidekick that was bitten by a vampire but was mutated to help some organization’s cause. The girl with the monsters on her hand is human but wants some sort of revenge (I think?) and uses the monsters’ power. They drag the boy along as bait for the 7 purebloods (kinda)

omg i remember all of this but i don’t know the name of it please help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Crimezone](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=65424)** fits most of your description, including the fact that they use the main character as bait, and that there were 7 "pure bloods".

According to mangaupdates, it's still ongoing, and last update was almost a year ago.

Synopsis from [mangaupdates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=65424):

> [image: Cover Image]
>
> The people of Earth live in a society where vampires aren’t just real but dangerous. Although humanity has been able to keep them under control and even take the night away as the vampire’s natural habitat, some of them have adapted. Hesperides, a relatively new breed of vampires, have adapted over hundreds of years in order to be able to go outside during dusk when the sunlight is at its weakest and feast on humans.
>
> Aburaya Shiro, a high school kid, lives in a town where there has not been a vampire attack in years, but adults keep warning them of going outside at dusk. Shiro and his classmates take this warning lightly and head out at dusk only to find out one of their classmates who they thought they knew well turns out to be a Hesperides. With all his classmates violently murdered, the only way Shiro was able to survive was with the help of a different classmate, Ichijoji Eruka, who doesn’t seem to be human herself.